# How do I write tests against POE EasyDBI?

Tags: perl, poe

I'm looking for some ideas or techniques to write tests against code that uses an `EasyDBI session` for accessing data in `mysql`. I don't want the `EasyDBI session` to be aware of being tested, so I was hoping to find a way to mock a `DSN` or something like that. But, It's not clear to me how I might do that.

Anyone had/solved this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using DBD:Mock which is pretty nice. When I set up my easy dbi component I used DBD:Mock: as the dsn. Then in the options I passed the result sets I wanted to return.

```
my @result_set = (list of stuff);

my $eDBI = POE::Component::EasyDBI->spawn(
    alias               => 'eDBI',
    dsn                 => "DBI:Mock:",
    username            => "",
    password            => "",
    options             => { 
        AutoCommit => 0, 
        mock_add_resultset => \@result_set,
    },
    no_connect_failures => 1,
    reconnect_wait      => 2,
    max_retries   => 5,
    connect_error => [ $alias, "dbi_failure", 5 ],
    connected => [ $alias, "dbi_connected" ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Test::Database::Tutorial` / `Test::Database` this is what you need. Or you create the test database from your `__DATA__` with `:cache:`